# Remove rows from data.frame according to a rule in R

Tags: r, dataframe, row

In a data.frame, I would like to automatically remove a row with 'NA' on `Column_E` if there is another row with the same info in all the other columns, such that:

```
Column_A   Column_B   Column_C    Column_D      Column_E
A121       NAME1      A321        2019-01-01    NA
A121       NAME1      A321        2019-01-01    2020-02-01
A123       NAME2      A322        2019-01-01    2020-01-01
A123       NAME2      A322        2019-01-01    NA
A124       NAME3      A323        2019-01-01    2019-01-01
A124       NAME4      A324        2019-01-01    NA
```

The output should be:

```
Column_A   Column_B   Column_C   Column_D       Column_E
A121       NAME1      A321        2019-01-01    2020-02-01
A123       NAME2      A322        2019-01-01    2020-01-01
A124       NAME3      A323        2019-01-01    2019-01-01
A124       NAME4      A324        2019-01-01    NA
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select rows where there is no `NA` value or there is only 1 row in the group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(across(Column_A:Column_D)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Column_E) | n() == 1)

# Column_A Column_B Column_C Column_D   Column_E  
#  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>      <chr>     
#1 A121     NAME1    A321     2019-01-01 2020-02-01
#2 A123     NAME2    A322     2019-01-01 2020-01-01
#3 A124     NAME3    A323     2019-01-01 2019-01-01
#4 A124     NAME4    A324     2019-01-01 NA
```

---

Same logic in `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[, .SD[!is.na(Column_E) | .N == 1], .(Column_A, Column_B, Column_C, Column_D)]
```

and base R :

```
subset(df, ave(!is.na(Column_E),Column_A, Column_B, Column_C, Column_D, 
          FUN = function(x) x | length(x) == 1))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Column_A = c("A121", "A121", "A123", "A123", "A124", 
"A124"), Column_B = c("NAME1", "NAME1", "NAME2", "NAME2", "NAME3", 
"NAME4"), Column_C = c("A321", "A321", "A322", "A322", "A323", 
"A324"), Column_D = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", 
"2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01"), Column_E = c(NA, "2020-02-01", 
"2020-01-01", NA, "2019-01-01", NA)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```